# Are bonuses provided by consumable food items permanent?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Food in games such as this often heals you for some amount of health. But I noticed that food shows a "First Time Bonus" window when viewing it.

[image: inventory screen looking at the food tab and unconsumed food]
*mmmmmmm food...*

Consuming it changes the "First Time Bonus" text to "Consumed" and a spoon and fork icon is shown next to the item's name.

[image: inventory screen looking at the food tab and consumed food]
*mmmmmmm consumed food...*

The bonus does appear to be applied as shown on the right side of the screen but...

**Is the bonus provided by the consuming food permanent?**

Comment: Doesn't Johannes tell you about this when he first sets up the alchemy shop?

Comment: He may have, but I must have missed it if he did, and of course we can't go back to see the dialogue history. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same question and did some spoiler-free searching around, according to two sources, the bonuses are permanent:

> The stat boost is a one time thing and is permanent for each new dish
>   you eat. Afterwards, food only heals a bit of health when used.

One user then wonders if it is only permanent for the game session:

> It does last after restarts as well? I'm afraid to quit the game and
>   have to cook all of this food again. D:

To which someone else replies:

> It lasts even after you reboot the game.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/692850/discussions/0/1638662230385491403/

The second source:

> You may have noticed the "prepare" option, which allows you to use
>   ingredients to prepare new foods, but may not have fully understood
>   what the "first time bonus" menu represents.
>
> So food can be used for several different purposes: you can eat it to
>   regain health, pass it off to the old woman in the hub to complete
>   quests, or eat it for permanent first consumption bonuses. Yep, those
>   stat bonuses are permanent and will persist throughout the entire
>   game, so long as you eat that food type once. See that little fork and
>   spoon icon near the Rice Ball? That means you've eaten that type of
>   food and have already reaped the bonus effects.
>
> What you're going to want to do is work your way down the entire
>   "prepare" menu and eat everything you can (preferably in the middle of
>   a boss fight to get more use out of food) to power up. Ingredients can
>   be purchased off the shop in the hub, grinded from enemies (check the
>   archive in the pause menu to see what each enemy drops), and
>   synthesized from this very "prepare/craft" menu.
>
> The bonuses for individual pieces of food often aren't stark, but
>   could be the difference between barely killing a boss and failing.

https://www.destructoid.com/bloodstained-guide-craft-every-food-item-you-can-at-least-once-557993.phtml

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion. Fortunately, they mark which food items have been consumed.